# Fetching database into a tree

Tags: php, mysql, tree, fetch

I have a database like this for a restaurant automation system that I'm coding to get experience in php and mysql.

```
productcat  |  productname  |  productdesc  |  price  |
-------------------------------------------------------
Drink       |  Coke         | Ice cold coke |  3
Drink       |  Sprite       |Ice cold sprite|  3
Food        |  Kebab        |Delicious kebab|  10
Food        |  Rice         | Delicious rice|  5
```

I want to fetch them into a tree that divided by categories.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $restadi") 
or die(mysql_error()); 

//urunler kategorilerinin altina yerlestiriliyor
echo '<div id="menu">';
echo '<ul>';
while($db = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 
echo '<li class="kategori"><a href="#">'.$db['productcat'].'</a></li>';
echo '<ul class="urun"><li><a href="#">'.$db['productname'].'</a></li></ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>'
```

Obviusly this doesnt work the way I want. How can I achieve what I want here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my sloppy English.

Comment: build the html by hand first. That'll show you how to build the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to don't want to make tree from result in PHP, you can try this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $restadi ORDER BY productcat");

//urunler kategorilerinin altina yerlestiriliyor
echo '<div id="menu">';
echo '<ul>';
$lastCategory = "";
while($db = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{ 

    if ($lastCategory != $db['productcat']) {
        // close opened ul of subitems (skip first false positive change of category)
        if (!empty($lastCategory)) {
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '<li class="kategori"><a href="#">'.$db['productcat'].'</a></li><ul class="urun">';
        $lastCategory = $db['productcat'];
    }
    echo '<li><a href="#">'.$db['productname'].'</a></li>';
}
// if there was at least one product, close last product list
if (!empty($lastCategory)) {
   echo '</ul>';
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Yes this is just the way I want it. Thanks!